# Use Cocoapods for private iOS Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift3, cocoapods, private

I'm working on an iOS framework and I would like to make it available to other developers to integrate within their "client" apps by including them in their Podfile, such as:

```
pod 'MyFramework'
```

But I can't share the actual source code for it due to some licensing restrictions. The examples I found online for developing iOS frameworks and setting up their podspec files are typically pointing to a repository on github or others and that seems to make the source code available in the developers' app after they run:

```
pod install
```

Do I have to share the source code from my framework with the developer? What is the best way (on both the framework setup in cocoapods and the client app in its Podfile) to make sure I can share MyFramework.framework but not its source code?
Note that I'm using Swift 3 for this project.

Thank you

al

[image]

---

Podfile (client):

```
target 'TestSDK' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
pod 'MySDK', :path => '/path/to/SDK/'
  # Pods for TestSDK
end
```

MySDK.podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|  
    s.name              = 'MySDK'
    s.version           = '1.0.0'
    s.summary           = 'A really cool SDK that logs stuff.'
    s.homepage          = 'http://example.com/'

    s.author            = { 'Name' => 'sdk@example.com' }
    s.license           = { :type => 'Apache-2.0', :file => 'LICENSE' }

    s.platform          = :ios
s.source = { :http => 'https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame/src/master/MySDK.zip' }
    s.ios.deployment_target = '9.3'
    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MySDK.framework'
end
```

Comment: https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/

Comment: Thank you @New16. I will go through it and if you don't mind I'll let you know if I have any other questions.

Comment: I guess I'm almost there.. but the test project still shows the source code under Pods > Development Pods > FRAMEWORK_NAME

Comment: I uploaded the zip file that contains my framework to a bitbucket repository instead of a website and I initially struggled to get the URL that I should use for it in the podspec, but then I got it, but the source code still shows up in the demo project.

Comment: Development Pods is for team. Please show the podspec file.

Comment: `code`
d::Spec.new do |s|  
    s.name              = 'MyFram'
    s.version           = '1.0.0'
    s.summary           = 'A really cool SDK that logs stuff.'
    s.homepage          = 'http://example.com/'
    s.author            = { 'Name' => 'sdk@example.com' }
    s.license           = { :type => 'Apache-2.0', :file => 'LICENSE' }

    s.platform          = :ios
s.source = { :http => 'https://bitbucket.org/myuserid/testsdkrepo/src/master/MyFram.zip' }
    s.ios.deployment_target = '9.3'
    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFram.framework'
end  
`code`

Comment: `d::Spec.new do |s|  
    s.name              = 'MyFram'
    s.version           = '1.0.0'
    s.summary           = 'A really cool SDK that logs stuff.'
    s.homepage          = 'http://example.com/'
    s.author            = { 'Name' => 'sdk@example.com' }
    s.license           = { :type => 'Apache-2.0', :file => 'LICENSE' }

    s.platform          = :ios
s.source = { :http => 'https://bitbucket.org/myuserid/testsdkrepo/src/master/MyFram.zip' }
    s.ios.deployment_target = '9.3'
    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFram.framework'
end  
`

Comment: Sorry, novice user of stackoverflow :(

Comment: With the above set up, it shouldn't show. Give me the Folder Structure where the source code is visible. If your class is public, the public methods are visible and not its implementation.

Comment: I added a picture of my dir structure above.

Comment: I can tell when I run the pod install on the client project that it doesn't take time to download the framework from the link that I provided, which is on bitbucket.

Comment: Okay run `pod cache clean YOUR_FRAMEWORK` and `pod install`. CocoaPods master repo doesn't update unless there is any changes in the PodSpec.

Comment: $ pod cache clean MySDK
1: MySDK v1.0.0 (External)
2: MySDK v1.0.0 (External)
It asked: "Which pod cache do you want to remove?"
I entered 2 then issued the command again and it removed both. 
But I still can't see the MySDK.framework in the TestSDK project (after I open TestSDK.xcworkspace)
By the way, my Podfile under TestSDK directory contains: 
`target 'TestSDK' do  
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks  
  use_frameworks!  
pod 'MySDK', :path => '/path/to/SDK/'  
  # Pods for TestSDK  
end`

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are saying. Can you send a copy of your Podfile and Podspec files.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help others. I ended up solving this issue by hosting the zip file that contains the framework along with my README.md and LICENSE (and later a CHANGELOG.md) and pointed the podspec's s.source to it. The only issue that I have now is that on cocoapods.org, it shows that the language is in Objective-C rather than Swift, but I think that should be an easy fix. Otherwise, I'm now able to have the framework on trunk and use Pod MySDK in a client app.

Comment: Thanks @New16 for your assistance. Not sure if you know about that language setting, but I got the private pod working by following your leads and doing more research :)